# Draw curved lines with css or canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I need to draw dynamic curved lines to show flight durations.

Any idea how I can do it?

I was try with clean css but have some rendering problems, I think only method is to use canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `SVG` it's a bit more browser agnostic I suppose.

[SVG Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#search=SVG)

[Canvas Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-canvas)

Something like this in your HTML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="190px" height="160px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Of course this could be generated via `Javascript` and then rendered. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw0oqq5y/1/)

[SVG Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

A Brief intro into the dynamic JS generation would be something along these lines. :

Create your dom element :

```
<svg id="flight" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

Now we add some JS attributes that you will generated based on variables in flight info:

```
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var flightPath = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"path");

flightPath.setAttributeNS(null,"id","path_1");
//This is what you need to generate based on your variables
flightPath.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M10 80 Q 95 10 180 80");
//Now we add our flight path to the view. 
document.getElementById("flight").appendChild(flightPath);
```

Add some CSS Animation to make it a little prettier and you end up with the following example :

[JSFiddle Dynamic](https://jsfiddle.net/t93tmh8m/)

Comment: This is a great solution! You could easily have the JS calculate the arc of the path based on the width of the SVG element. Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/t93tmh8m/2/

Comment: @Moob can we also animate airplane from left to center?

Comment: @vrabota I don't see why not. Here's [an example of SVG motion along a path from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion). I've added a quick example in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t93tmh8m/3/) - with a little more effort the creation of the `animateMotion` element could be done with the JS itself too. P.S. You'll probably want to use a polygon that looks like a plane in place of the circle ;)